# My component won't display in React, after I moved it in it's own file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, react-state

Here is my Question component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Question(props){
    <div>
        <h1 className="question">{props.allQuestions.props.question ? 
        props.allQuestions.props.question : 
        'Loading..'}
        </h1>

        {props.allQuestions?.props.allAnswers?.map(quest =>
        <button className="quest" key={props.key}>{quest}</button> 
        )}


        {props.currentQuestion > 4 ? '' : <button className="nextQuest" onClick={props.nextQuestion}>Next question</button> } 
        
    </div>
}
```

And here is my App component:

```
import React from "react";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Question from './components'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import "./index.css"

function App(){
  const [allQuestions, setAllQuestions] = useState('Loading...')
  const [hasEnded, setHasEnded] = useState(true)
  const [currQuestion, setCurrQuestion] = useState(0)
  
  
  // function that gets new questions
  function newQuiz() { 
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=multiple')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => 
      setAllQuestions(data.results.map((item) => {
      return{
        id: nanoid(),
        question: item.question,
        correctAnswer: item.correct_answer,
        allAnswers: [...item.incorrect_answers, item.correct_answer]
        
      }

    })))
    

  }

  // Function that start sthe quiz
  function startQuiz(){
    setHasEnded(prevHasEnded => !prevHasEnded)
    
  }
  function endQuiz(){
    if(currQuestion > 4){ 
    setHasEnded(prevHasEnded => !prevHasEnded)
    }
  }
  


  useEffect(() => {
    
    if(hasEnded === false){ 
    newQuiz();
    }else{
      console.log(123)
    }
    
    
  }, [hasEnded])


  // Function that gets the next question 
  function nextQuest(){
     
    setCurrQuestion(prevQuest => prevQuest + 1)
    
  }

  
  console.log(hasEnded)

  return(
    <div>
    
     {hasEnded ?
       
      <div>
        <h1>Quiz</h1>
        <h4>5 Questions, 5 correct answers.</h4>
        <button className="nextQuest" onClick={startQuiz}>Start Quiz</button>
      </div> 
      
     :
```

> And here, I'm trying to display my Question component

```
      <Question 
      allQuestions = {allQuestions[currQuestion]}
      question = {allQuestions[currQuestion].question}
      allAnswers = {allQuestions[currQuestion].allAnswers}
      nextQuestion = {nextQuest}
      key = {nanoid()}


      />
     }

      
    </div>
  )

}

export default App
```

After I save and click the start quiz button (which flips the state of hasEnded), nothing shows up and I get multiple errors in the console. Before this, there was no Question component, everything was in the App component and it worked without a problem.

Comment: Your Question component doesn't return anything

Comment: didn't notice that, but I made it to return but again, it's the same error, here is it : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')".

Comment: you must add 'return' statement before '<div>..' in Question component

Comment: Already fixed that, but  it's the same error, here is it : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')".

Comment: console.log is your friend. This is wrong ```props.allQuestions.props.question``` check the log of ```props.allQuestions```